# Generating sequence numbers in Java from the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, sequence

How to generate sequence numbers and assign them to each object in java?

for example i have the following,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class MyMaxUDOComparable
{

    public static Integer findMaxScore(List<testVO> emps)
    {
        Integer maxScoreTotal = 0;

        for (Iterator<JobFitSurveyConfigVO> iterator = emps.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
        {
            testVOempl = (testVO) iterator.next();

            if (empl != null)
            {
                maxScoreTotal += empl.getSalary();
            }

        }
        return maxScoreTotal;
    }

    public static void main(String a[])
    {

        List<testVO> emps = new ArrayList<testVO>();
        emps.add(new testVO(10, "Raghu", 10,1));
        emps.add(new testVO(120, "Krish", 10,2));
        emps.add(new testVO(210, "John", 10,3));
        emps.add(new testVO(150, "Kishore", 10,4));
        testVOmaxSal = Collections.max(emps);

        System.out.println("Employee with max Id: " + maxSal);
        System.out.println("maxScoreTotal: " + findMaxScore(emps));
    }
}

class testVOimplements Comparable<testVO>
{

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer salary;
    private Integer sequenceNumber;

    public testVO(Integer id, String name, Integer sal,Integer sequenceNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = sal;
    }

    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(Integer salary)
    {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Integer getSequenceNumber()
    {
        return sequenceNumber;
    }

    public void setSequenceNumber(Integer sequenceNumber)
    {
        this.sequenceNumber = sequenceNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(JobFitSurveyConfigVO emp)
    {

        return this.id.compareTo(emp.getId());
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return id + "  " + name + "   " + salary;
    }
}
```

in the above class, i have assigned values to all the objects for `Sequence Number` and if I remove any object from the list then the `Sequence Number` has to be re generated.

how to do this in java, would some one help me on this please?.

Comment: It depends, do you want to re-use sequence numbers or do they simply increment?

Comment: Why are `id`, `salary`, and `sequenceNumber` of type `Integer`? Wouldn't `int` be better? Or can they be `null`?

Comment: when any object is deleted do you want objects following the deleted object to have sequenceNumber = sequenceNumber -1 ?

Comment: @Java-ledge it depends but the final result is like the object's sequence number should be like 1,2,3,4,5,..etc..

Comment: @Mason Andreas and i have tried to fullfill your requirement. but I don't think  there is any other functionality java provides out of the box.

Comment: check my post it may help you! i used methods for adding and removing elements.

Comment: @Yash Thank you and will check, please give me some more time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void deleteObjFormList(JobFitSurveyConfigVO emp,List<JobFitSurveyConfigVO> emps)
    {
        int i = emps.indexOf(emp);
        emps.remove(i);
        for(int j=i;j<emps.size();j++)
        {
            JobFitSurveyConfigVO emp1 = emps.get(j);
            emp1.setSequenceNumber(emp1.getSequenceNumber()-1);
        }
        return;
    }
```

I this this should be a function to remove the object from the list.

Comment: That won't compile (missing return value).

Comment: Since OP code never set sequence number to begin with (yeah, probably an error), this will cause NPE. ;-)

Comment: this code is written with assumption that arrayList already contains correctly assigned sequence numbers. and will handle operation to delete single object from the array.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate the list and set the sequence number.

Be aware that your constructor is not assigning the sequence number, so although you provided values, they are all `null`. If you changed type to the more sensible `int`, they would be `0`.

```
// Renumber (aka resequence) the emp records
for (int i = 0; i < emps.size(); i++)
    emps.get(i).setSequenceNumber(i + 1);
```

Comment: or better solution is to just do sequenceNumber = sequenceNumber -1 for all object that are following the deleted object.

Comment: @Java-ledge True, but since there is no example of a remove being done, the position of the removed value may be unknown. A separate full renumber may also be better if multiple elements are removed. It all depends, but this implementation will always work, even if not necessarily the most efficient, and since OP is boxing all integers, efficiency is not the top of the list.

Comment: For down-voter, please explain why this answer is not useful?

Answer (score 0):

**try this way**

```
public static void main(String a[])  {

List<JobFitSurveyConfigVO> emps = new ArrayList<JobFitSurveyConfigVO>();

    ArrayList<Integer> seq = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    addElement(seq, emps, 10, "Raghu", 10);
    addElement(seq, emps, 120, "Krish", 10);
    addElement(seq, emps, 210, "John", 10);
    addElement(seq, emps, 150, "Kishore", 10);

    System.out.println("Display : "+emps);

    removeElement(2, seq, emps);
    System.out.println("Removed : "+emps);

    addElement(seq, emps, 210, "John2", 10);
    System.out.println("Added : "+emps);
}
```

*Add Element and Remove Element methods*

```
public static void addElement(ArrayList<Integer> seq, 
       List<JobFitSurveyConfigVO> emps, int id, String name, Integer salary)  {

     int size = seq.size();
     Collections.sort(seq); // Make sure they are in Sequence.
     if (size > 1) {
         for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
             int check = seq.get(i-1);
             if ( (check + 1) != (seq.get(i))) {
                 seq.add(check + 1);
                 emps.add(new JobFitSurveyConfigVO(id, name, salary, (check + 1)));
                 break;
             }
             if (i+1 == size) {
                 seq.add(seq.get(i) + 1);
                 emps.add(new JobFitSurveyConfigVO(id, name, salary, (seq.get(i) + 1)));
             }
         }
     }else if (size == 1 && seq.get(0) == 1) {
         int check = seq.get(0);
         seq.add(check + 1);
         emps.add(new JobFitSurveyConfigVO(id, name, salary, (check + 1)));
     }else{
         seq.add(1);
         emps.add(new JobFitSurveyConfigVO(id, name, salary, 1));
     }
}
public static void removeElement(int index, ArrayList<Integer> seq, List<JobFitSurveyConfigVO> emps){
    if (index < seq.size()) {
        emps.remove(index);
        seq.remove(index);
    }else {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
```

*constructor*

```
public JobFitSurveyConfigVO(Integer id, String name, Integer sal,Integer sequenceNumber) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = sal;
    this.sequenceNumber = sequenceNumber;
}
```